# ORA-12560 : TNS:protocol adapter error

Tags: oracle11g

Im trying to log to ORACLE with comand  SqlPlus / as sysdba but I receive an error ORA-12560 : TNS:protocol adapter error. I read everything but i can't fixed it. It is strange because before I was able to connect. I search for OracleServiceORCL but instead I found OracleServiceXE in Services.msc. Can someone help mi to fix the problem@

Answer (score 0):

Check variables ORACLE_SID and TWO_TASK and ORACLE_HOME

What happens when you run

```
net start "OracleServiceORCL"
```

Comment: I found OracleServiceXE not OracleServiceORCL. I have Express edition.

Comment: I didn't find such variables ORACLE_SID and TWO_TASK and ORACLE_HOM

Comment: Sorry, but I am super begginer. Thank you for answering

Comment: Perform this:

---    C:\>set | findstr /I ora    ---

and then this:

---    sqlplus / as sysdba     --- (without the ---)

Comment: C:\Users\Anatoli>set | findstr /I ora
Path=D:\app\Anatoli\product\12.1.0\client_1;D:\app\Anatoli\product\12.1.0\client
_1\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\
Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\
Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Fil
es\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Anatol
i\AppData\Roaming\npm
TNS_ADMIN=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN

Comment: C:\Users\Anatoli>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Mon Nov 24 20:46:26 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Comment: First you gotta know what is the correct Oracle Home, what is the correct database name (SID). I presume your Oracle Home is "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server", which means your database is 11gR2. That directory, should be in the ORACLE_HOME variable. Then, you should put the correct SID in ORACLE_SID, which will either be XE or ORCL. Look at both of these, where it shows that ORACLE_SID is set : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3fAzolGCXFo and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPDxLUZ1VRQ The Windows service may be started automatically, after you login as SYSDBA, byexecuting STARTUP